# Which sequences converge in the topological space $\left(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{J}_{\text{Lexicographic}}\right)$?

Tags: general-topology

Which sequences converges in the topological space $\left(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{J}_{\text{Lexicographic}}\right)$?

That i have tried:

For each $(p,q)\in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ we have that the sequence $\{(p,q),(p,q),(p,q),\cdots,(p,q)\cdots$} coverges to $(p,q)$ for all $(p,q)\in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.

Am I ok?

Is it correct? Do you have a different example approach?

Comment: Constant sequences always converge.

Comment: The first thing you should do is write down that the open sets are in this topology.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** Apart from the eventually constant sequences, note that every point which is not a successor, or the minimum, is the limit of a sequence of smaller points. Can you characterize these points? If so, then you can characterize the sequences which converge.

Comment: The sequences that have the form: $\{(n,1),(n,2),(n,3),(n,4) \dots\}$ for a fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$ converges to $(n+1,1)$. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

$(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), \ldots$ converges to $(2,1)$.

Comment: For me is not clear, please could you explain me why, thank you

Comment: @LFRC Because every open set containing $(2,1)$ also contains some points $(1, x)$.

Answer (score -1):

ALERT: sorry the next answer is not correct:

I think that you are right.

As we have that $\left(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{J}_{\text{Lexicographic}}\right)$ is a discrete space, it has the trivial convergence. By definition, a space $ (X, \mathcal{T})$ has trivial convergence if the only sequences that converges are the constant sequences.

Comment: That's not true.

Comment: It's not discrete.